# What exactly happens when you reset a SQL replication in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm using RavenDB 3.0.30115 and it feels like SQL replications take a lot longer to process when you reset them than they used to. For example, I have a `Contacts` collection with 31 documents in, and a simple replication script to copy properties from that into Postgres. When it was first created, it seemed to execute quickly. However, I recently added a new property into the replication, and so reset it in Studio in order to copy across the new property. Looking at the SQL replication graphs showed this:

[image: SQL replication after reset]

Considering there are only 31 items in the collection, I don't understand why I am seeing batch sizes in the thousands, never mind several of them, and the replication knows which collection it pertains to so I don't see why it would be processing other documents, particularly since no items in the collection reference any other documents.

Could someone please shed some light onto what exactly is going on in the background when you ask for a SQL replication to reset?